# Index Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: java

I am working on a minecraft mod. The id system for EntityC4 is not working. The code is

```
public static List C4 = new ArrayList();  

public static EntityC4 getitemfromnumber(int num)
{
    EntityC4 entity = (EntityC4)C4.get(num);

    return entity;
}
public static void createdetonater(EntityC4 c4, int num)
{
    C4.add(num, c4);


}
public static int getnum(){
     int num = 0;
      for(boolean a = true; a != false;){
          EntityC4 c = (EntityC4)C4.get(num);
          System.out.print("current num : " + num);

            if(c != null)
            {
                a = false;
            }else{
                System.out.print("entity " + num + " is null" );
         num++;
            }
      }
      return num;
   }
```

And when I use getnum() an error shows up that says

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT:Ty and the loop was supposed the first non-existent space in the list.

Comment: tell us at what line this is occurring to make answering your question easier.

Comment: Don't you need to populate C4 with some content first? AFAIK, your exception means that C4 is initialised (in your first line) with an empty array, and is not populated with any content...

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an ArrayList instead of a Map for the C4 variable?  It just seems like your are trying to duplicate Map functionality in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a new `ArrayList C4`, you never put anything in the `List`, and then you ask it for the element at index `0`. This element does not exists since the List is still empty, and it throws an exception.

You can avoid this exception by adjusting your method

```
public static EntityC4 getitemfromnumber(int num)
{
  EntityC4 entity = null;
  if ( num >=0 && num < C4.size ){
    entity = (EntityC4)C4.get(num);
  }
  return entity;
}
```

This will avoid the exception, but you will get stuck in your loop since you never find the element (which isn't available in the list)

Comment: The question says that the exception is thrown when getnum() is invoked, not getitemfromnumber(num).

Comment: Correct. I re-wrote the wrong method. But the checks he can place around the get remain valid, and the remark about getting stuck in the loop when the list is empty also

Answer (score 1):

`C4` is obviously empty if you just call `getNum()`, thus the exception saying that the index you are accessing doesn't exist.

You might want to pre-populate the list by calling `createdetonater(..)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is coming from

```
EntityC4 c = (EntityC4)C4.get(num);
```

which states your `C4` is empty, you would like to do a `not null` and `notEmpty` check on your list.

In order to check the reason why `C4` is empty do a trace on `createdetonater` and see where its being called.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message tells you everything: you're trying to get the zeroth element from a list that has no elements. You probably need to add something to `C4`,

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite your loop to use a counter then it will avoid this error.  I am not sure exactly what your code is trying to do though (return first non-null instance?), so the loop below may be incorrect.

If you are trying to store a map of ID to entity, then you should probably use a HashMap<Integer,EntityC4> instead.

```
for(int num = 0; num < C4.size(); num++)
{
    EntityC4 c = (EntityC4)C4.get(num);
    System.out.print("current num : " + num);

    if(c != null)
    {
        return num;
    } else
    {
        System.out.print("entity " + num + " is null" );
    }
}
// throw an exception or whatever else your code should do here...
```